# splitting ms access database to multiple backend

Tags: ms-access

I have an ms access database with forms which I split .!
I was wondering if I can further split the backend and move specific tables to a second backend .
The problem I am trying to solve has to do with the 2GB size limit , where MS access fails, but if I am able to move couple of tables which fills up during my ETL , I could still be within the 2gb limit and can save the day

I split the ms database using the DBSplitter utility and needs to split the backend further

Comment: I would highly suggest moving to a more robust database system

Comment: thanks Daniel , this is for an interim solution until the migration project is complete

Comment: @RakeshRamesan You can use Linked Tables - whereby different tables exist in different `.accdb` or `.mdb` files - but AFAIK you can't _shard_ tables. But I'm going to agree with Daniel in that you should already be moving away from Access (especially as there's no evidence MS is interested in supporting it for much longer...) - I assume you've read the migration guide? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/migrate-an-access-database-to-sql-server-7bac0438-498a-4f53-b17b-cc22fc42c979

Comment: @Dai: Please don't post undocumented FUD statements. There is no evidence that Microsoft is _not_ interested in supporting Microsoft Access.

Comment: @Gustav MS has made repeated statements [that VBA is on the way out](https://www.accessforever.org/post/the-microsoft-access-team-s-position-on-new-outlook) - and what is Access without VBA? The fact its SQL engine remains fundamentally unchanged since 1997, with zero support for any new ISO SQL features added after SQL-92 should be enough to convince anyone concerned with software-longevity that Access is not a suitable platform for development anymore.

Comment: @Dai, the link you quoted does not at all support what you state here. The fact that a certain part of the product (SQL engine) was not significantly updated in the lat 26 years and the product is still around and in active development, is not a convincing clue for the products immediate demise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little or nothing special about how splitting a database works, and thus no need to use the built in tools for this purpose.

To move out a few tables from an existing split database?

Simply create a new blank database, and use the import from the external data tab of the ribbon. Import the few tables you want.

Now, re-open the original back end data file, and delete those 2-3 tables you moved into the other new (second) back end.

Now, close above, and open the front end and delete the 2-3 tables that we once linked to the original back end, and now using the linked table manager, add back the 2-3 linked tables but pointing them now to the back end #2.

Also, I assume that before you start this ETL process, you have compaced the data file. And I assume you have ALSO turned off row locking feature. The row locking feature in Access can cause MASSIVE bloating and file growth, so I recommend you turn this feature off.

The option I am speaking of is found here:

File->option->client settings

Then this:

[image]

I have seen the above reduce bloat and growth by many times, and in some cases you see next to no growth after some update operations.

So, depending on how your ETL code works, I would consider/try the above option. Do note that you have to exit Access, and re-start for the above setting to take effect.

Comment: thank you Albert for taking the time to answer in detail, this resolved the issue . I split the database and moved the heavy tables to separate database and it seems to work . ! your help is much appreciated !